Euclidean division of $P(X,Y)$ by $D(X,Y)$
I want to divide a polynomial $P(X,Y) \in \mathbb C [X,Y]$ by $D(X,Y)$.
To do so I was wanting to start by dividing $P(X,Y)$ and treat $X$ as a constant:
$$P(X)(Y) = Q(Y)D(X,Y) + R(Y)\ \text{ and } \ 0 \le \deg_Y(R)<\deg_Y(D)$$
Now I'd like to divide it in $\mathbb C [X]$ but I have no idea how to proceed, and I don't really know what the end formula looks like.

It is not clear you can proceed in the way you mention. First, $Q$ and $R$ might depend on $X$. For examples, consider the equations $X^2 = X \cdot X + 0$ and $X + Y = 1 \cdot Y + X$. Moreover, treating $X$ as a constant might cause the quotient to no longer be a polynomial in $X$, e.g., $XY = \frac{1}{X} \cdot X^2Y + 0$.
Instead, the division algorithm in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ allows you to write
$$P(X,Y) = Q(X,Y)D(X,Y) + R(X,Y),$$
where either $R(X,Y) = 0$ or $R(X,Y)$ is a linear combination of monomials, none of which are divisible by the leading term of $D(X,Y)$. An algorithm for finding such an expression is given in Theorem 3 of Chapter 2, $\S$3 of Cox, Little, and O'Shea's book Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms (Google Books Link).
